# Hardware not compatible in host OS but compatible in guest OS

Tags: wireless-networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am planning to buy a wireless usb adapter for my laptop. I have a Windows laptop currently and might change to Macbook in the future. The wireless usb adapter not compatible with macOS. I know if I dual boot Macbook to Windows will allow the wireless usb adapter to work. My question is, if I run Windows as guest OS in virtualbox and MacOS be my host OS, will my wireless usb adapter detectable by my Windows guest OS?

Comment: If the device is visible to the virtual machine, and drivers are provided so the device can function, then the device will function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is yes. Virtual box will disconnect the device from the host OSes control and give essentially direct access to the USB device to the guest OS. The net effect is that windows sees the actual hardware device and doesn't know its being passed through another OS, so the native Windows drivers just work